# Enumerate all permutations of a list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, permutation, combinations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

I want to get all possible combination having values range from 0-7.

For eg

```
arr[0]= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
arr[1]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0
arr[2]=2,3,4,5,6,7,1,0

arr[3]= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
arr[4]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0
arr[5]=2,3,4,5,6,7,1,0

arr[6]= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
arr[7]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0
arr[8]=2,3,4,5,6,7,1,0

arr[9]= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....
```

and so on.

I want to get all possible combination with no repeating digits from a given set of value i.e 0-7.

Comment: Why have you tagged the question with "probability"?

Comment: Looks like you're on your way--keep chuggin'. Seriously--what language? What have you tried? There are examples of this all over the net--what didn't work about them?

Comment: @aioobe Because the probability of anyone helping with the question as-is is low.

Comment: @Dave Can you provide me solution i have tried all over net i didnt find it. I think you are great researcher and you can provide me the url where it has been posted..

Comment: @Ronak Search for "combination permutation" plus whatever language you're trying to do this with. Please show some effort--this is a 100%-solved problem, some languages even have a function call that does it *for* you.

Comment: ruby has a method [permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-permutation): `(0..7).to_a.permutation.to_a`

Answer (score 0):

indeed this will all depend on the language... Here is a short try in python:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> for p in permutations(l):
    print p


(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5)
...
```